# Calculate the Sum of Values using ng-repeat in Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am newbie to Angular js.I am just trying to calculate the sum of Values of each row using angular js.Here, I am dynamically adding and removing rows.
For Eg: Let's say first row value is 30, Now I added one row with value 30, then total should be show 60 like this.

```
1.        30
2.        30
3.        50
Total    120
```

HTML Code:

```
 <table id="t1" style="border:none;">
        <tr><th>Start</th><th>Stop</th><th>Downtime(In Min)</th><th>Reason</th></tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in invoice">
        <td><input  type="text" required ng-model="$invoice.start" name="r1[]"></td>
        <td><input  type="text" required ng-model="$invoice.stop"  name="r2[]" ng-blur="diff($invoice)"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="r3[]"  ng-model="$invoice.diff"/></td>
        <td style="border:none;"><a href ng-click="remove(item)">X</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border:none;">
        <td style="border:none;"><a href ng-click="add()">+</a></td>
      </tr>
        </table>
<span class="labelCode">Total Downtime</span><input required type="text"  name="Tot_D" ng-value="d1()"/></span></br>
```

Angular JS:

```
     $scope.d1=function(){
                        var total = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < $scope.invoice.length; i++){
                var product = $scope.invoice[i];
                total += parseInt(product.diff);
            }
            return total;

                       }
//Calculate the Difference between two times

     $scope.diff = function(item) {
        item.diff = computeDiff(item.start,item.stop);
      }

      function computeDiff(start, stop) {
        if (start && stop) {
          var s_hr = start.split(":")[0];
          var s_min = start.split(":")[1];
          var e_hr = stop.split(":")[0];
          var e_min = stop.split(":")[1];

          return Math.abs((parseInt(e_hr) - parseInt(s_hr)) * 60) + Math.abs(parseInt(e_min) - parseInt(s_min))
        }
      }
```

Now, it just showing NaN. I don't know what is wrong.
Please help out.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is $invoice defined

Comment: @zargold It is defined into controller, $scope.invoice =  [{
  start :"7:00",
  stop:"7:30" ,
  reason: "M/C Ready to Start",
           }]

Comment: The object inside `$scope.invoice` doesn't seem to have any `diff` property.

Comment: @Kushagra There is no use of diff property here, Main concern is only d1() function.

Comment: `total += parseInt(product.diff);` inside your `$scope.d1` function uses `diff` property. If it's undefined as you're saying, then the result will be `NaN` only.

Comment: parseInt tries to access diff? Where is diff?

Comment: @Kushagra Diff will be output of difference between start and stop.It will calculate automatically.

Comment: @Babaji Could you create a jsfiddle test case with the diff calculation code?  The problem seems to be most likely with that calculation.

Comment: @Kushagra I am trying to create the jsfiddle but output is not showing, but output is showing into My computer..I will just the update the Diff function in above code.